# Publish and subscribe variables between twincat 2 and twincat 3

Tags: twincat, twincat-ads

I need to send a variable via ethernet from a Twincat 3 to a Twincat 2. Is it possible? How could I do that?

Answer (score 6):

You can use Network Variables for this purpose. There's good documentation available on the Beckhoff site: https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcsystemmanager/fieldbus/rtethernet/tcrtethernet_intro.htm&id=

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the tcDataExchange.lib, the FB_WriteAdsSymByName (or FB_ReadAdsSymByName) looks good for your task.

The same library has other FBs that work in a more automatic way, e.g., triggering an update when a value is changed.
You might need to make a search for 'tcDataExchange.lib' in both the TC2 help file and the Infosys as they seem - at least on my PC - a little confused about which FBs are available.